# Auto refresh div content, loaded by jquery include ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am loading output from `now_playing.php` (shoutcast now playing content) using a jQuery include ajax call, as [sugested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934150/3379674), and it works well.

My code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#now_playing").load("now_playing.php");
});
</script>

<div id="now_playing"></div>
```

I just need that div output content updated every 5 seconds or so.
Which code can i add to script or div part for that?
Thank you!

Comment: Correct your code in your message please, some is missing

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:
Put your `load()` in a function, then use a `setInterval` to call it every 5 seconds.

```
function loadNowPlaying(){
  $("#now_playing").load("now_playing.php");
}
setInterval(function(){loadNowPlaying()}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval` for that. Like

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#now_playing").load("now_playing.php");
    ...
}, 5000);
```

It'll execute the load the `now_playing.php` and do the other stuff you want every 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

try to do it with setInterval():

```
$(function(){
   setInterval(function(){$("#now_playing").load("now_playing.php")},5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learned Magicprog.fr, augustoccesar and Edan Feiles's suggestions, and decided Magicprog.fr's solution is best, because it first loads now_playing.php output, then just updates it at given interval:

```
<script>
function loadNowPlaying(){
  $("#now_playing").load("now_playing.php");
}
setInterval(function(){loadNowPlaying()}, 5000);
</script>
```

Thank you very much for help :)